# Efficient way to add multiple value in Map Collection

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create multiple users in redshift (say create user "abc" with password "xyz"). And same when a user got created redshift I am storing those usernames and their password in local MySQL Database, but password in encrypted format. My Current approach is:

```
Map<String, String> uNamePassForDB = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> uNamePassForRedshift = new HashMap<>();

listOfUsers.stream().forEach(u -> {
        String pass = //some random password generator;
        String encryptedPassword = //encrpts the password (i.e. pass)
        uNamePassForDB.put(u, encryptedPassword);
        uNamePassForRedshift.put(u, pass);
}

uNamePassForRedshift.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
      // creating redshift connection and executing create user command
}

uNamePassForRedshift.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
      // storing the encrypted password in my local MySQL Database
}
```

Currently, I store "username|password" after all users get successfully created in redshift. Is it feasible to store username|password when it is successfully created on Redshift? This approach works for me. But how can I improve this approach? How to simplify this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest you avoid the `collection.stream().forEach()` construct since the Stream-API should follow the [*non-interference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) principle. Moreover, you can call the `forEach` method to anything `Iterable` including `List` or `Set`.

Now back to your issue. The problem of changing the `Map` values has been discussed many times and I still wonder JDK doesn't provide a clear solution to this issue. Personally, I believe one of the best approaches is a plain iteration and replacement the values themselves. Even in the [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)+ version, this is a legit way:

```
for (String user: listOfUsers) {
    String pass = "random password";
    String encryptedPassword = "encrypted password";
    uNamePassForDB.put(user, encryptedPassword);
    uNamePassForRedshift.put(user, pass);
}
```

Since you have tagged [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream), try to think in a declarative way as what the result of `Stream` would *be* rather than what it would *do* (this is a difference from the procedural `for-loop` thinking). The only way I am aware of that doesn't violate the non-interference principle and doesn't cause side-effects (the password generation is rather still questionable) is:

```
// Each Stream should do ONE thing

final List<Credential> credentials = listOfUsers.stream()
    .map(user -> new Credential(user, /* random password */ ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

final Map<String, String> uNamePassForDB = credentials.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Credential::getUser,                                     // key
                 Credential::getEncryptedPassword));                      // value

final Map<String, String> uNamePassForRedshift = credentials.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Credential::getUser,                                     // key
                 Credential::getPassword));                               // value
```

Where the immutable `Credential` class is created for the help:

```
public static class Credential {
    private final String user;
    private final String password;
    private final String encryptedPassword;

    public Credential(final String user, final String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        // I suggest this to avoid inconsistency
        this.encryptedPassword = /* encrypt password */           
    }

    // getters
}
```

Comment: Right making a class Credential is perfect. I am violating  non-interference principle since i am adding element in my stream right?

Comment: @user10144071: You should not modify another mutable source inside the `Stream`. Read more at [Parallelism - Side Effects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#side_effects).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
listOfUsers.stream().map(this::createUsernamePass).forEach(this::store);
```

Where createUsernamePass is a method creating a data object holding your username, password and encrypted password and store(userNamePass) is a method doing the database inserts.

(This is written on an iPad and not tested, but the idea can be considered)

You can probably do a parallel execution of this as well do make it faster.

Comment: Right make sense to make two methods, one for storing and one for creating users.